# Updating Product Quantity in Database After Order Success

Tags: php, mysql, database, cart, product-quantity

I am creating a cart functionality in my project. Every Thing works Perfectly, But I am facing an error when updating availables product quantity of every ordered product by product id. I am getting the id but I can understand that how to get available product quantity from databases of each product.

My Code

```
        $pid = array();
        foreach ($_POST['product_id'] as $proid => $pidvalue) {
        $pid[] .=  $pidvalue;
        }
        $product_id = implode(', ', $pid);
        // ==========================================


        $pquantity = array();
        foreach ($_POST['product_quantity'] as $pq => $pqvalue) {
        $pquantity[] .=  $pqvalue;
        }
        $product_quantity = implode(', ', $pquantity);
        // ==========================================



        // I am using static value 
        // How can I get the dynamic value



        // Trying  to Run Update Query
        for ($i = 0; $i < (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])); $i++) {        


        $quantity_after_order[] = 15 - ($pquantity[$i]);

        $update = array();

        foreach ($_POST['product_id'] as $up => $upvalue) {
        $update[] .= "UPDATE product SET pquantity = '$quantity_after_order[$i]' WHERE pid={$upvalue} " . " 
        <br>";
        }
        }
        

        "<br>" . print_r($update)  . "<br>";
```

Output:

```
            Array ( [0] => UPDATE product SET pquantity = '4' WHERE pid=7
            [1] => UPDATE product SET pquantity = '4' WHERE pid=32
            [2] => UPDATE product SET pquantity = '4' WHERE pid=20
            [3] => UPDATE product SET pquantity = '4' WHERE pid=31
            )
```

Comment: Hello. Please clarify your question. Or are are you just asking for how to connect to the DB and get quantity for specific product (`SELECT pquantity FROM product WHERE pid=...`)?

Comment: I select quantity from database but only last value comes. I want to select quantities according to pid. Product of each quantity which user order update after success of order.

Comment: I do not see it in the code (only `UPDATE ...` is there), but make sure you execute only one SQL command at a time. I.e. not `SELECT ...; SELECT ...;`, but only `SELECT...`.

Comment: my problem is now solved thanks for your help. I run while loop in for loop which selects pquantity from database and give to update query after subtracting from order quantity